# Pass multiple values into global variables in Postman?

Tags: variables, global, postman

How can I pass multiple values into a Postman global variable?

Example:
`"test" variable accepting values like ["a","b"]`

I have tried adding `["a","b"]` as a global variable value and ran the test but it throws:
`"ReferenceError | test is not defined"`

JSON as below:

```
{
    "enabled": true,
    "key": "test",
    "type": "text",
    "value": "[\"a\",\"b\"]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `pm.globals.set('my_var', JSON.stringify('["a", "b"]'))` work for you. I’m not sure where you’re setting this from but this should do the job.

It’s easier to capture things like this from a previous request, rather than manual set it.

You could then access the value you need by using `JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('my_var'))[0]`

Comment: somehow I can't upvote bcos I get a message saying its less than 15 reputations